# iOS 7 Background Fetch When the App is Not Running

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, background-process

I've written a simple application in order to test and monitor how the [background fetch](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler:) feature works in iOS7.

First of all, I've set UIBackgroundMode options in my Info.plist file.

[image]

Then;

I added to below code into **application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:** method in **AppDelegate.m**:

[image]

At last, I've implemented the **application:(UIApplication *)application 
  performFetchWithCompletionHandler:** method as requested.

[image]

Every time I click **Debug->Simulate Background Fetch** button, it changes the application's batch number and works as expected.

However, I've never been able to make it work when the application is not running (not even in the background mode, just not running).

Apple says that when the application is not running and OS wants to execute the following methods respectively:

```
application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:
```

So my question is that is there a way to test background fetch when the app is not running?

I am testing this on my **iPod 5th Gen with iOS 7.1**.

Comment: I don't think so as you can never know when the OS will perform this. If it works under the conditions you've tested it then everything *should* work when you release it... There's no way to trigger this in a live environment without using silent push notifications.

Comment: Try scheduling a Local Notification on one of the cases and see if it triggers.

Comment: I tried to display a local notification whenever it is called but I couldn't find a way to trigger the background fetch when the app is not running. I just wanted to make sure if it really is doing what it offers.

Comment: How long are you wait? For example my app wakes every 1-2 hours for fetch, I see my debug messages in logs when leave device for night.

Comment: @sage444 are you sure your app is not running? (I mean terminating the app by sliding up after home button) or has it been running in background?

Comment: I can sure say about run in background

Comment: In background, I saw it was running interminently. I'd like to see if it starts running in background some time after it was terminated.

Comment: If app crashes system relaunch it (sure 100%), but if user kill app I think it newer more run (but not sure:)

Comment: @sage444 may be true: there was a change in iOS7 and iOS8 around respecting user killing app intentionally. So you may need to test it causing crash / not by killing app in task manager.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Edit 2:** Note that if a user kills the app from the app switcher, the background fetch will never happen again. This is working as Apple intended. See the related ["Understanding When Your App Gets Launched into the Background"](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW7) docs for details:

> In most cases, the system does not relaunch apps after they are force
>   quit by the user. One exception is location apps, which in iOS 8 and
>   later are relaunched after being force quit by the user.

And an old developer forums post (the link unfortunately no longer exists)...

> "If you kill an app from the multitasking UI, the system will never
>   automatically launch the app again. The logic here is that, if the
>   user has killed your app, they probably want it to stay dead."

You could make a simple GET request, eg: "http://dev.example.org/?ping=1" to your web server then grep the access.log on the web server for "?ping=1"

**Edit:** Another method to test the app being launched in the background (eg: without being able to double tap the home button and switch to it) is by creating a background-only scheme. Go to Product -> Scheme -> Manage Schemes and then duplicate your default scheme.

[image: scheme settings]

Then edit the new scheme and click the Options tab and check "Launch due to a background fetch event" - when you run your app it'll be launched directly into the background, as it would through normal use.

[image: launch with background fetch]

Comment: Is the part about iOS not re-launched if the app was explicitly killed still true? It seems to hold for my app, which uses the background fetching. But I just launched and then killed the Gmail app and sent myself an email, and the Gmail app still posts a notification.... wtf?

Comment: Gmail app uses another mechanism (Push Notifications) together with BackgroundFetch to accomplish that.

Comment: @MikeAsdf thanks, added a docs link and removed the broken forums link.

Comment: @taber how to update current location to my server via api in every one minute, when app was closed/suspended?

Comment: did you get any clue?