# Does BackgroundFetch works even when app is killed

Tags: ios, background, fetch

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval:
    UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum];
}
```

I set minimum time interval as above and below method works fine and fetch data for ever 10min (since i set minimum time interval) when app is in background..

```
- (void) application: (UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:
(void(^) (UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler{
    fetch data....    
}
```

will the above performFetchWithCompletionHandler: method run even when app is killed???

Comment: Big NO if you app going to be crashed or killed that BGTask not working anymore.

Comment: The answer is NO. When no NSRunLoop is running no code is running

Comment: The same discussion happens here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22607871/ios-7-background-fetch-when-the-app-is-not-running  ~~